# Update a table field in MySql when a match with primary Key Occurs

Tags: php, mysql

Iam using a table in Mysql database and here there is a field called as `First_Seen and Last_Seen` and one of the field `ID` is marked as primary Key.

Now suppose my record is like this

```
12445555555|1|4444444855|2017-03-09 15:02:55|abc|134|M|SOME_RANDOM_NAME
```

Out of these `1244555555` field is made primary key.

SO if I try to insert this record into database it is inserting properly with both first_seen and last_seen as `2017-03-09 15:02:55`.

But whenever the script executes the same command after 10 min (say) because the id is made primary key,the next record with different time like this is not inserted.

```
12445555555|1|4444444855|2017-03-09 15:12:55|abc|134|M|SOME_RANDOM_NAME
```

So all I wanted to do instead of inserting duplicate record into database I want to update the last_seen field.Any suggestions on this.Because even the script executes the same record n no of times it won't be reflected in database.

This is the db_insert.py script which takes the record from the csv file and extract the fields and insert into db

```
time = record[6]
            try:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
        # Trying to create a new record
                sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `my_table` (`ID`,`F1`,`F2`,`First_Seen`,`Last_Seen`,`F3`,`F4`,`F5`,`F6`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql,(id,f1,f2,time,time,f3,f4,f5,f6))
                connection.commit()
            finally:
                connection.rollback()
connection.close()
```

All i wanted is whenever the duplicate entry occurs matching the `id` field then i need to replace the time with the time field in the current row and put it in last_seen.

This is what iam expecting.

```
12445555555|1|4444444855|2017-03-09 15:02:55|2017-03-09 15:12:55abc|134|M|SOME_RANDOM_NAME|something_else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

INSERT INTO table (id, column1, column2) 
VALUES(1, 'inserted value1', 'inserted value2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1="updated value 1", column2='updated value 2'